# URl works in postman returns full news array but returns empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch, postman

In postman when i use the url below the news property on the response in full with articles

```
https://api.currentsapi.services/v1/search?country=us&language=en&apiKey="..."
```

But in javascript I'm getting an empty news array.

Here is the javascript:

```
function displayNewsResults(responseJson){
    console.log(responseJson)
}

let newsBaseUrl = 'https://api.currentsapi.services/v1/search'
let newsApiKey = '...';

function getNews(country) {

    let params = {
        country: country,
        language: 'us',
        apiKey: newsApiKey
    }

    let queryString = formatQueryParams(params);
    let url = newsBaseUrl + '?' + queryString;

    console.log(url)

    let req = new Request(url);
    
    fetch(req)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            else {
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }
        })
        .then(responseJson => displayNewsResults(responseJson))
        .catch(err => {
            $('#js-error-message-news').empty().text(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`).show();
        })
}
```

The function `displayNewsResults` returns:

```
{status: "ok", news: Array(0), page: 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code seems correct and the result is also correct, the mistake however is that in your code you're calling the API with the `language` parameter set to `us` instead of `en`